# How does Garbage Collection collects objects that have inheritance

Tags: c#, .net

consider the following code:

```
class Base
{
}
class Derived : Base
{
// some code
}
```

and from main if we do

```
Derived d = new Derived();
```

I have two questions:

Q1-We know when we do `new Derived();`CLR allocate a `Derived` object in the heap. But since `Derived` derives from Base, `Derived` implicit constructor also calls `Base`'s implicit constructor, does it mean that there is also a `Base` object allocated in the heap?

Q2-(if the answer to Q1 is true) In GC's context, we refer to all reference type variables as roots. So for example, variable `d` is a root, and this root points to `Derived` object only. Here is a problem, there is no root variable to `Base` object, in theory `Base` object is always marked as unreachable by Garbage Collector and then get swept. which is obviously not correct, so does it mean that an implicit root variable will be assigned to `Base` object to keep it reachable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood the nature of inheritance. There is just one object created here, an object of type `Derived`. The inheritance means that Derived gains some properties inherited from Base, but that does not mean another object of type Base is created. So to Q1, the answer is no. Therefore there is no need to answer Q2. The GC has one memory allocation to track, that for Derived.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new instance of a derived object (e.g. `Derived d = new Derived();`), a single object is allocated, not separate objects for the derived class and its base class.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine they were both structs and you had to compose the derived object manually. You might end up with something like;

```cs
public struct Base {
    ...
}
public struct Derived {
    public Base base;
    ...
}
```

The memory required for Base is contained within the memory footprint of Derived.